# Differential equation which has following solution $y=A+B\tanh(\frac{x-D}{C})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

How can I find the ODE from the following solution:

$$y=A+B\tanh\left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right)$$

$A,B,C,D$ are constants.

These are some examples of ODE with that solution:
$$Ay''-B(y-1)y'=0$$

Other
$$Ay''+2yy'=0$$
Other
$$y'=1-y^2$$

and other

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= ay^2+ by+ c$$

I need to solve this equation to get something with $\tanh$.
I have started with an idea but have not been able to complete it.

> Note that:
> $$z:=\frac{y-A}{B}=\tanh\left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right) \text{ satisfies } z''=\frac{2}{c}zz'=\frac{2}{c}(1-z)(1+z)z$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last differential equation you give

$$y'=ay^2+by+c$$

has, under the condition $\Delta=b^2-4ac \ge 0$, the following solutions

$$y=-\dfrac{1}{2a}\left(b+\delta \tanh(\frac{\delta}{2}x+\dfrac{\delta c}{2a})\right)$$

(where $\delta:=\sqrt{\Delta}$).

Reference: https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/13/01/

Remark: you can "fit" values $a,b,c$ in order that they generate predefined parameters $A,B,C,D$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=A+B\tanh\left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right)$$
$$y\cosh \left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right) =A\cosh \left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right)+B\sinh\left(\frac{x-D}{C}\right)$$
More simply:
$$z(t) =A\cosh (t)+B\sinh (t)$$
This is a solution of a second order linear differential equation.
$$z'(t) =A\sinh (t)+B\cosh (t)$$
$$z''(t) =A\cosh (t)+B\sinh (t)$$
Therefore:
$$z''=z \implies z''-z=0$$
$$(y\cosh (t))''-y\cosh (t)=0$$
$$y''\cosh (t)+2y'\sinh (t)=0$$
$$y''+2y'\tanh (t)=0$$
Where $t= \dfrac {x-D}C$.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate one constant after the other. You get rid of $A$ by just taking the derivative
$$
y'=\frac{B}{C}\cosh\left(\frac{x-D}C\right)^{-2}.
$$
Now a logarithmic derivative will remove $B$
$$
\frac{y''}{y'}=-\frac{2}{C^2}\tanh\left(\frac{x-D}C\right)
$$
Now insert this back into the first equation to eliminate the transcendental function. Unfortunately that revives $A$ and $B$
$$
y=A-\frac{BC^2}2\frac{y''}{y'}.
$$
Start again with a simple derivative
$$
y'=-\frac{BC^2}2\frac{y'''y'-y''^2}{y'^2}
$$
and continue again with a logarithmic derivative
$$
\frac{y''}{y}=\frac{y''''y'-y'''y''}{y'''y'-y''^2}-2\frac{y''}{y'}
\\~\\
y''(y'-2y)(y'''y'-y''^2)=yy'(y''''y'-y'''y'')
$$
This is a 4th order ODE as required for 4 integration constants. While terms on the left and right cancel, I do not see how that could simplify the equation.